# Can't access JSON data from google sheets API link

Tags: json, api, google-sheets

v3 of google sheets API has been deprecated. The link does not work anymore `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<spreadsheet_id>/od6/public/values?alt=json`. It shows this error  "*The Sheets v3 API has been turned down. Further information can be found at: https://clo"ud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api*"
Can anyone help me with the updated link format of v4 to access the JSON data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new url is

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
```

here is an example of parsing

```
var id = '______your_speadsheet_id________';
var gid = '0';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("json").innerHTML=myItems(data.substring(47).slice(0, -2))  
  );
function myItems(jsonString){
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table><tr>'
  json.table.cols.forEach(colonne => table += '<th>' + colonne.label + '</th>')
  table += '</tr>'
  json.table.rows.forEach(ligne => {
    table += '<tr>'
    ligne.c.forEach(cellule => {
        try{var valeur = cellule.f ? cellule.f : cellule.v}
        catch(e){var valeur = ''}
        table += '<td>' + valeur + '</td>'
      }
    )
    table += '</tr>'
    }
  )
  table += '</table>'
  return table
}
```

see the announcement here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api

a complete application in html

```
<html>
<title>Google Sheets json endpoint V4</title>
<author>Mike Steelson</author>
<style>
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
th,td{border: 1px solid black;}
</style>
<body>
<div id="json">json here</div>
<script>
var id = '1n-rjSYb63Z2jySS3-M0BQ78vu8DTPOjG-SZM4i8IxXI';
var gid = '0';
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+id+'/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid='+gid;
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("json").innerHTML=myItems(data.substring(47).slice(0, -2))  
  );
function myItems(jsonString){
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var table = '<table><tr>'
  json.table.cols.forEach(colonne => table += '<th>' + colonne.label + '</th>')
  table += '</tr>'
  json.table.rows.forEach(ligne => {
    table += '<tr>'
    ligne.c.forEach(cellule => {
        try{var valeur = cellule.f ? cellule.f : cellule.v}
        catch(e){var valeur = ''}
        table += '<td>' + valeur + '</td>'
      }
    )
    table += '</tr>'
    }
  )
  table += '</table>'
  return table
}           
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It's working but it's downloading the text file how can it be shown in the browser in JSON format?

Comment: I have completed my answer ... to get only the json `.substring(47).slice(0, -2)`