# Get an entire Google Sheets worksheet's JSON definition

Tags: json, google-sheets

So, I'm looking for a way to get an entire Google Sheet worksheet as JSON. Not just the data (cell content) in the worksheet, but also the formatting, colors, merged cells, formulas, references and whatnot.

This used to be possible using the v3 API which was turned down on September 30th.

A call to `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<sheet id>/<worksheet id>/public/values?alt=json` would get you the entire worksheet as it is stored on the Google side.

Is there any other way to get the entire definition of a Sheet as JSON?

There is an answer here: [Can't access JSON data from google sheets API link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343189/cant-access-json-data-from-google-sheets-api-link) that suggests something similar, however, this just returns the cell values, not the entire markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just in case someone else needs this: To get the entire sheet, including its markup and layout and formatting and references and formulas, and so on, use:

```
    curl \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[YOUR_SHEET_ID]?includeGridData=true&ranges=[YOUR_RANGE_IN_A1_NOTATION]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```